# SOAPHandler and Spring Autowire

Tags: spring, autowired, soaphandler

I'm trying to inject a Spring Service into a SOAPHandler but the reference is always null.

I tried extending SpringBeanAutowiringSupport and using:

```
public class FuelServiceSOAPHandlerBase extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext>, InitializingBean {
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationService authenticationService;

    @Override
    @PostConstruct
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        LOG.info("AuthenticationHandler - PostConstruct");
        SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
    }
    ....
}
```

It does not work, authenticationService is always null. I tried also to get the Bean throw

```
authenticationService = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(((HttpServletRequest)context.getMessage().getProperty(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST)).getSession().getServletContext()).getBean(FuelAuthenticationService.class);
```

But the ServletRequest is null. I'm executing the Webservice-Call throw SOAPUI.

Does anybody knows what the error is?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I solved using @Resource and not @Autowire